# Using lapply to subset a list of character lists in R

Tags: r

I have the following line that subsets a character list correctly:

```
> cpc_data2[[1]]
 [1] ""     "Week" ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""    
[11] ""     "SST"  "SSTA" ""     ""     ""     ""     "SST"  "SSTA" ""    
[21] ""     ""     ""     "SST"  "SSTA" ""     ""     ""     ""     "SST" 
[31] "SSTA"
> cpc_data2[[1]][which(cpc_data2[1][[1]] != "")]
[1] "Week" "SST"  "SSTA" "SST"  "SSTA" "SST"  "SSTA" "SST"  "SSTA"
```

I would like to subset every list in `cpc_data2`.  How should I do this?  I have tried the following, clearly my syntax is incorrect:

```
> cpc_data3 = lapply(cpc_data2, function(x) x[which(x[[1]] != "")])
> head(cpc_data3)
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
lapply(cpc_data2, function(x) x[x!=''])
```